# Counting the number of comparisons in Java project

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, counting

I would love some input as to how to count the comparisons in my "insert" "delete" "search" and "print" functions. What this program entails is it can add 'Students' to a list, remove them from said list, print out the list, and other functions.  However, it needs to be able to count how many comparisons are made when inserting, deleting, searching, and printing. I know this needs a for loop, but I can't quite get it right. Are there any suggestions?

The following is my code (be warned, it is large):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment3{
static String students = ""; //Records of matching students
static int matches = 0; //Number of matching students
static Set <Student> names = new HashSet<Student>(); //HashSet to store Students

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{ 

    int ID = 0;                 
    String lastName;        
    double GPA;             
    boolean run = true;

    while (run == true){
        String menu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "1) Loading students" +
                "\n2) Adding new student" +
                "\n3) Removing student " +
                "\n4) Searching students" +
                "\n5) Printing students " +
                "\n6) Quit");

        //Loading students from a text file
        if (menu.equals("1")){
            String inputFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input file:");
            File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

            while (in.hasNext()){ //Loading names from text file to array!
                ID = in.nextInt();
                lastName = in.next();
                GPA = in.nextDouble();
                Student student = new Student(ID,lastName,GPA);
                names.add(student);
            }
            in.close(); //Done loading from file, closing input!
        }

        //Adding more students to your list
        if (menu.equals("2")){
            String idString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter an ID for student");
            ID = Integer.parseInt(idString);
            lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a last name for student");
            String gpaString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a GPA for student");
            GPA = Double.parseDouble(gpaString);
            Student student = new Student(ID,lastName,GPA);
            names.add(student);
        }

        //Remove student
        if (menu.equals("3")){
            String idString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter an ID for student to remove");
            deleteStudentByID(Integer.parseInt(idString),names);
        }

        //Search
        if (menu.equals("4")){
            String searchMenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "1) Search by ID" +
                    "\n2) Search by name" +
                    "\n3) Search by GPA");


            if (searchMenu.equals("1")){


                int count = 0;
                for (int n=1; n<ID; n++)  
                    count++;   // insert a[n] into a[0..(n-1)]



                String idSearch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter ID number");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found " + (findStudentByID(Integer.parseInt(idSearch),names) +  " Student\n" + students));
                System.out.println("The number of comparisons is " + count );

            }
            if (searchMenu.equals("2")){
                String nameSearch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter last name");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found: " + findStudentByName(nameSearch,names) + "\n" + matches + " student(s) with last name of " + nameSearch);
            }
            if (searchMenu.equals("3")){



                String gpaSearch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter GPA");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found " + (findStudentByGPA(Double.parseDouble(gpaSearch),names) +  " Student(s)\n" + students));
            }
        }

        //Print
        if (menu.equals("5")){
            String printMenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "1) Print to console" +
                    "\n2) Print to file");
            //Console
            if (printMenu.equals("1")){
                Iterator <Student> iter = names.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()){
                    Student tempStudent = iter.next();
                    System.out.println("ID: " + tempStudent.getID() + " Name: " + tempStudent.getName() + " GPA: " + tempStudent.getGPA() + " Hash Code: " + tempStudent.hashCode());    
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Output to console complete");
            }
            //Text file
            if (printMenu.equals("2")){
                String outputFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Output file:");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
                Iterator <Student> iter = names.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()){
                    Student tempStudent = iter.next();
                    out.println("ID: " + tempStudent.getID() + " Name: " + tempStudent.getName() + " GPA: " + tempStudent.getGPA() + " Hash Code: " + tempStudent.hashCode());    
                }
                out.close(); //Done writing to file, close output
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Output saved to " + outputFileName);
            }
        }

        //Quit
        if (menu.equals("6")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

//Delete a student
static void deleteStudentByID(int id, Set <Student> list){ 
    matches = 0;
    students = "";
    Iterator<Student> iterator = names.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Student student = iterator.next();
        if (student.getIDHash() == Integer.toString(id).hashCode()){
            matches++;
            students = "ID: " + student.getID() + " Name: " + student.getName() + " GPA: " + student.getGPA() + "\n";
            list.remove(student);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted " + matches +  " Student\n" + students);
            break;
        }   
    }

    if (matches == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Student not found");
    }
}
//Search by ID
static int findStudentByID(int id,Set <Student> list){
    matches = 0;
    students = "";
    for (Student student : list){
        if (student.getIDHash() == Integer.toString(id).hashCode()){
            matches++;
            students = "ID: " + student.getID() + " Name: " + student.getName() + " GPA: " + student.getGPA() + "\n";
        }
    }
    return matches; 
}
//Search by name
static String findStudentByName(String name,Set <Student> list){
    matches = 0;
    students = "";
    for (Student student : list) {
        if (student.getNameHash() == name.hashCode()){
            matches++;
        }
    }
    if (matches > 0){ 
        return "YES";
    }
    return "NO";
}
//Search by GPA
static double findStudentByGPA(double gpa,Set <Student> list){
    matches = 0;
    students = "";
    for (Student student : list){
        if (student.getGPAHash() == Double.toString(gpa).hashCode()){
            matches++;
            students += "ID: " + student.getID() + " Name: " + student.getName() + " GPA: " + student.getGPA() + "\n";
        }
    }
    return matches; 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just have a counter variable, say:

```
int count;
```

and increment it each time the program make a comparison.

Comment: Right, I understand that I will need an int count and a for loop, but how would I set that up? For instance if I had a for loop, I would increment count++, but to what would I compare it to if I was searching by last name? Last name is a string.

Comment: @TrevorE You have `while` and `for` loops in your `delete...` and `find...` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern in combination with [Abstract Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

In other words, your example is not object oriented at all. You're in functional programming, that's why this counting will mean serious code duplication (in many places you will have to do `count++`). Introduce `Comparison` class and a chain of `AbstractComparison` implementations.

Comment: How will I implement the count++ though? How would the for loop be set up?

Comment: count++ will be implemented in `ComparisonFactory#counted()`, and called from `AbstractComparison#counted()`. `for` loop will use the chain of comparisons

Comment: Could I see a sample? Maybe the one for lastName or GPA? I'm just not grasping this.